# Insert multiple data with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert multiple data in one table, however I got an error that says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO author (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('Rasmus', 'Lerdorf')INSERT INT' at line 1

Here's the method:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO author (firstname, lastname)  VALUES ('Roal', 'Dahl')";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO author (firstname, lastname)  VALUES ('Rasmus', 'Lerdorf')";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO author (firstname, lastname)  VALUES ('Jane', 'Doe')";
```

Do I need to create a for loop for this? How could this work?

Comment: delete `.` here `$sql .=` in both queries

Comment: Unless you're using mysqli_multi_query or PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, you cannot use multiple inserts in one query. Separate them out.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this :

```
  $sql = INSERT INTO author ( firstname, lastname) VALUES ('Roal', 'Dahl'), ('Rasmus', 'Lerdorf'), ('Jane', 'Doe');
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, mysqli and PDO cannot execute multiple statements in a single query. There are alternatives like [mysqli_multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php), but that is not really what you need.

Your query can have multiple rows added by appending extra sections after `VALUES` like so:

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO author (firstname, lastname)  VALUES ";
$sql .= "('Roal', 'Dahl'), ('Rasmus', 'Lerdorf'), ('Jane', 'Doe')";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use two options:

**mysqli_multi_query**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO author (firstname, lastname)  VALUES ('Roal', 'Dahl');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO author (firstname, lastname)  VALUES ('Rasmus', 'Lerdorf');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO author (firstname, lastname)  VALUES ('Jane', 'Doe');";
if(!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)){
echo 'Error query:'. $mysqli->error . '.';
}else{
//do any operation
}
```

**Or use one query like:**

```
$sql = INSERT INTO author ( firstname, lastname) VALUES ('Roal', 'Dahl'), ('Rasmus', 'Lerdorf'), ('Jane', 'Doe');
if(!$mysqli->query($sql)){
echo 'Error query:'. $mysqli->error . '.';
}else{
//do any operation
}
```

Change `$mysqli` with your connection